Add xyz position to a Quaternion orientation
I have 3d point, with a Quaternion location (w,x,y,z)
How to Add a position (x,y,z) to this quaternion matrix ?
Is there any way to convert a Quaternion matrix into something like (Position+Rotation+Scale) matrix(s) ?
I need this to modify a 3d animation file.

Quaternions contain rotational information only, not spacial position information. What you are asking to do makes no sense. You need to give us more details about why you are trying to do this and maybe we can steer you in a better direction.
